# Is there a way to create a continuous distribution graph from discrete percentiles?

Tags: pandas, numpy, distribution

I have an underlying distribution that I know is 1-tailed (Packet Response time), but the service that runs the benchmark is opaque to me. It only returns a percentile table up to some number of nines like so:

```
Pct      Time
Median | 10
90% | 20
99% | 30
99.9% | 100
99.99% | 1000
```

I would to be able to estimate what a KDE with these parameters would look like, but I don't know how I would go about doing so.